# Batch file is not working

Tags: python, batch-file, pycharm, exe

```
     @echo off 
start c:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\anupam.soni\Desktop\WIND_ACTUAL\tool.py
    PAUSE
```

My script in tool.py is correctly working in **PyCharm IDE**, this bat is not working.
**Note : file path and python path is correct.**

Any other option to run python script independently

Comment: How is it failing, specifically? Please include error messages and relevant configuration information.

Comment: command window is automatically getting close when  I am trying to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `start` from your batch file - this opens a separate window for the console application `python.exe`, and when `python.exe` exits, it will close the console window. By eliminating `start`, it runs `python.exe` in the same session of `cmd` that the batch file is running in, and allows you to read any output from `python.exe` before exiting (because of the `pause` command).

Answer (score 0):

Python installations by default associate `.py` files with it and issues a command to run the interpreter `PATH_TO_PYTHON\python.exe "%1" %*`

So you should not need to call `python.exe` manually to call the script. You also do not need the start command at all.

Not sure why you need the batch to call a python script, but this would be perfect. always put the full path in quotes in case you hit whitespace in the paths.

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\anupam.soni\Desktop\WIND_ACTUAL\tool.py"
pause
```